# What are the results for Hats awarded on the latest Winter Bash

Tags: discussion

I know I got 11 hats, which should have resulted in being awarded 'The Milliner'hat. But since the Winter Bash closed at midnight everything has disappeared.  Does Stack keep a chart of who got what?

Comment: Cheers and hatters to all! Hope you get some sort of response. It was such great fun.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is all we get [Winter Bash 2019](https://winterbash2019.stackexchange.com/leaderboard). I don't think they put the hats into the stackexchange api, but there may be deeper magic.